# Wildcard in the middle of URL

Tags: python, url

I need to get from url programmatically all urls by increasing i but middle part is random combination of numbers and letters.

```
https://www.example.com/ark:/61903/3:1:33SQ-GRQJ-9DHS?i=463
```

I tried asterisk with no result.

```
https://www.example.com/ark:/61903/*?i=463
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You will need a list of the URLs you want to retrieve. If you can't get one, there's probably a reason you can't.

Comment: There's no standard way to ask a webserver for all URLs that match a pattern. If the pages are generated dynamically, it may not be feasible for the server to return such a list.